# Have I Correctly Defined the Set of Nonzero Complex Numbers $\mathbb{C^*}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

If the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C} = \{a+bi\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then what would be the definition of the set of nonzero complex numbers? Am I right in defining such a set as

$$\mathbb{C^*} = \{a+bi\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R} \ni a+bi \neq 0\}?$$

Also, if this definition of the set of nonzero complex numbers is correct, am I correct in concluding that the numbers $a+0i$, $0+bi$ $\in \mathbb{C^*}$ ?

Comment: If everything is in italics, the whole points of italics loses its meaning. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't have written $\Bbb R\ni a+bi\neq 0$, since it seems to imply that $a+bi$ is a real number. Writing $a+bi\neq 0\text{and} a,b\in\Bbb R$ should suffice.

Or, since $\Bbb C$ was already defined, $\{x\mid x\in\Bbb C, x\neq 0\}$, or $\{x\in\Bbb C\mid x\neq 0\}$.

Comment: Alright, so then my other question on whether the numbers $a+0i$, $0+bi$   $\in$ $\mathbb{C^*}$ would be correct?

Comment: only if $a\neq 0$ in the first case and $b\neq 0$ in the second.

Comment: I think the "$\ni$" in the question was being used to mean "such that".  This is terrible notation in my opinion, but some books do use it.

Comment: which notation for "such that" do you prefer as a mathematical symbol, our of curiosity?

Comment: @Benedict: $\text{ such that }$ or in case where space is scarce, $\text{ s.t. }$ also works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem defining "set of nonzero complex numbers" as $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Comment: Alright, so then my other question on whether the numbers $a+0i$, $0+bi$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C^*}$ would be correct?

Comment: Let'e be careful here. If $a=0$, then $a+0i$ actually is $0$, so you want to make sure that $a\ne 0$ in this case.Same thing happens with $0+bi$ as well, you want to let $b\ne 0$.

Comment: But if the number $a+0i$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C^*}$, how could $a$ possibly equal 0? It appears to me that the definiton of $\mathbb{C^*}$ necessitates that either the real or the imaginary part of a complex number is zero, but not both. Therefore, $a$ necessarily does not equal 0 by definition of our set, right? So it would seem to me to be unnecessary to specify that $a\neq0$ when the property of $\mathbb{C^*}$ implies it.

Comment: If you tell me "I have this complex number $a+0i$ and it is in $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$", then of course $a$ cannot be $0$ because it is not zero (you just told me that). But, if you just tell me "I have a number $a+0i$, tell me if it is is $0$", well, I don't know. It could be.

Comment: So yes, you are right. Given that we know $a+0i\in \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$, we can immediately conclude that $a\ne 0$.